# Rails and Sessions

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.1, session-cookies, session-storage

How to Set a Password for every http GET requests in rails for "student-course has_many :through association using users and sessions"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at using an authentication gem, looking at [RubyToolBox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication), here are a couple,

- Devise
- Authlogi
- Omniauth
- Restful-authentication